# Volley with https?

Tags: android, android-volley

I have problem with my Volley Rest. 
If the URL from **HTTP** it works and gets a response, but if from **HTTPS**, it does not work, response always **server error**.
I following [volley demo](https://github.com/smanikandan14/Volley-demo/tree/master/volleydemoapp/src/main/java/com/mani/volleydemo), for fix it, but the code is return null in line :

```
InputStream clientStream = VolleySampleApplication.getContext().getResources()
                              .openRawResource(R.raw.production_test_client);`
```

so how to fix it ? or any other solution ?

Comment: Have you had production_test_client cert file inside \src\main\res\raw?

Comment: Does your endpoint support HTTPS? Does it use a trusted or self-signed certificate?

Comment: sorry, i have find solution, i must setting configuration of my https in server

Comment: Hye Amay Diam, can you share with me the solutions ? i mean part setting configuration of https server . im having the same problem . you can email me at bonjaibonjai@gmail.com . thanks. .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
                 CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
             InputStream caInput = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.cert);
             Certificate ca;
             try {
                 ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
                 System.out.println("ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
             } finally {
                 caInput.close();
             }
             String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
             KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
             keyStore.load(null, null);
             keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);
             String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
             TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
             tmf.init(keyStore);
             SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
             context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
            mRequestQueue =Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext(), new HurlStack(null, context.getSocketFactory()));
```

For me that works, i do not know if is the best way, but could help you.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

**o fix mobile (likelihood):**

Under the direction from my friend: D, for a response https, tried in tests using tools fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), use fiddler> (http://www.blogs.progotik.com/using- fiddler-to-make-a-post-request /)

how to check fiddler, for example https my domain is **https: mydomain.com**:

1. hit https://facebook.com, https://google.com use fiddler response is
   200

   2. hit https: mydomain.com response is 502 bad gateway
   3. The response is hit http://api.mydomain.com 200
   4. http://mydomain.tk is the response 200
   5. Based on the conversation with my friend, the possibility for https: mydomain.com need to be set again
   6. I am searching via google, and I found a solution >> https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html
   7. I input https: mydomain.com, wait, then see the section Handshake Simulation
   8. ChiperSuite not compatible from android version 4.4.4 and below
   9. then I lowered the setting ChiperSuite at mydomain.com and its solve